# Error using sklearn.dataset

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to visualize some data. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/usrname/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/dddd.py", line 4, in <module>
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
from .base import clone
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
from scipy import sparse
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Below, there is the code to visualize the data.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
# We load the data with load_iris from sklearn
data = load_iris()
features = data['data']
feature_names = data['feature_names']
target = data['target']
for t,marker,c in zip(xrange(3),">ox","rgb"):
   # We plot each class on its own to get different colored markers
   plt.scatter(features[target == t,0],features[target == t,1],marker=marker,c=c)
```

I am using the the Python 2.7, Mac OS "Mavericks".

Comment: How did you install sklearn? It evidently requires scipy, which you may also need to install.

Comment: I've installed scipy via sudo pip install scipy

Comment: And can you run `from scipy import sparse` directly in the interpreter?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you can't try, or it gives the same error? If the latter, you will have to try reinstalling `scipy`, as `sklearn` won't work without it

Answer (score 1):

Check if the sckit-learn is working properly or not.

```
 nosetests -v sklearn
```

if it shows error try installing first Scipy by

```
pip install git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/
```